# Get previous state and update context object indirectly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am currently referring to a context object and updating in my child component as below:

```
setMyContextObjectData(prevState => {
    return {
        myGroupOrder: {...prevState.myGroupOrder},
        myGroups: {
        ...prevState.myGroups,
        'Section 1': myData.myGroups['Section 1']
        }
    };
});
```

Now there are multiple child components which are updating this context object.

If I want to not update this context object directly in my child components, but instead want to pass the information to parent component (via props)
and update the context object only in my parent component, can I use a local state in my child component and update that? If yes, how can I get the "prevState" for "myContextObjectData"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Parent

```
 const updateFromChild = (dataFromChild) => {
    setMyContextObjectData((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        ...dataFromChild,
      };
    });
  };
  <Child onUpdate={updateFromChild} />
```

// Child

```
 onUpdate({
    myGroupOrder: {// new data},
    myGroups: {
      'Section 1': {// new data},
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thanks...Actually initially in the context object, in myGroups, it has 'Section 1': {}, 'Section 2': {}...But after the code in parent is run, myGroups just has 'Section 1': {} i.e. 'Section 2': {} is removed....Again, there are multiple child components (i.e. Section 1/2) which are updating this context object.